# I have a #value error in my logical statement and checked examples and can't find the error

Tags: excel-formula

I have a #value error when trying to nest multiple IF(OR(AND statements.It works with 1 statement but when I nest them I get the value error.

What I am trying to say is:
IF (C7=True) AND 1 of the $A$6 = TRUE (either 11 OR 12) then show text1,
IF (C7=True AND 1 of the $A$6=True (either 6.7,8 OR 9)then show text2,
when both false
IF(C7=TRUE, then "text3", otherwise "-")

=IF(OR(AND(C7=TRUE,$A$6=11),AND(C7=TRUE,$A$6=12)),"Text1"),
IF(OR(AND(C7=TRUE,$A$6=6),AND(C7=TRUE,$A$6=7),AND(C7=TRUE,$A$6=8),AND(C7=TRUE,$A$6=9)),"Text2", IF(C7=TRUE,"Text3", "-"))

Comment: I am having a hard time following your logic.  Maybe add pseudo code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your equation is that you open with `IF(OR(AND))` when you want to open with `IF(AND(OR))`. However, since you want `C7 = TRUE` for `Text1`, `Text2`, `Text3` you can nest those inside like so `IF(C7 = TRUE, Evaluate A6, "Other")`.

Then, you just need to `Evaluate A6` using `OR` instead of continuously checking the value of `C7`

---

```
=IF(C7=TRUE,IF(OR(A6=11,A6=12),"Text1",IF(OR(A6=6,A6=7,A6=8,A6=9),"Text2","Text3")),"Other")
```

Comment: Thank you, That is much better syntax. I am going to apply it immediately.